# Equivalency of Modulo function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is it valid to take modulo of both sides of a complex eqn? I can't seem to pinpoint why, but say we want to find the solutions of this expression

$$2z^2=-4 \\ |2z^2|=|-4| \\ |z^2| = 2 \\ |z| = \sqrt{2}$$

However, it is fairly obvious there are many points on $|z|=\sqrt{2}$ that don't satisfy the first equation? $2(\sqrt{2})^2 \neq -4$

Comment: Depends on what you mean by valid. It is only a forward implication but not an equivalence. If $2z^2 = -4$ then $|z| = \sqrt 2$. However not all $z$ satisfying $|z| = \sqrt 2$ will satisfy $2z^2 = -4$.

Comment: If $z$ is allowed to be a complex number, there are solutions to $2z^2=-4$. If $z$ real none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have solved the equation **only for the amplitude of the complex variable $z$**. Any complex variable also comes with a phase, so you also need to solve it for the phase of $z$. Just express $z$ as $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r=\sqrt 2$ as you implied correctly and find the constraints on $\theta$.

Comment: Ah makes sense, so this line of reasoning is valid? Should be sufficient to show, like say some function $\frac{1}{2z^2+4}$ is analytic inside say, $C: |z|=1$ since $|z| = \sqrt{2} > 1$?

Comment: Yes. It is perfectly fine to say that and almost nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Taking modulus is legitimate but it does not yield the final answer. A better way is to write $z^{2}=-2$ which gives $z =\pm \sqrt 2 i$.

Comment: Sorry, so I'm a bit confused why the modulus removes the equivalence / generalizes?

Comment: @Infinitus If $z$ satisfies the given equation then $|z|=\sqrt 2$ as you have shown. The converse of statement is not always true. If $|z|=\sqrt 2$ it does not follow that $z$ is a solution of the given equation.